# Erro na formatação do dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, galeria

Boa noite a todos, Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar com o DomPdf.
Estou utilizando como base do projeto o codeigniter e bootstrap[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].
Preciso Gerar um PDF com uma galeria de produtos, o problema é que não consigo forçar uma quebra de linhas.
Os itens sempre aparecem um na frete do outro.

```
//controller
    public function ImprimirTrabalho(){

        #pesquisando modelo do trabalho
        $pesquisaModelo = $this->Trabalho->trabalho_layout($this->uri->segment(2));
        #passando Modelo do trabalho para a variavel modelo
        $modelo = $pesquisaModelo['0']['layout'];

        ob_start();
        $this->load->view('header_impressao');
        $this->load->view($modelo);
        $pdf = ob_get_clean();

        $this->pdf->loadHtml($pdf);
        // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        $this->pdf->setPaper('A4', '');
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $this->pdf->render();
        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $this->pdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));


    }
```

Catálogo de produtos
    
        diofgudofui
        diofgudofui
        diofgudofui
        diofgudofui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde! Para quem está passando ou vai passar pela mesma dificuldade eis como solucionei.
A Biblioteca DOMPF trabalha com css 2.1 e ccs 3, sendo assim a soluções rotineiras que implementamos podem nos trazer problemas no que diz respeito a posicionamento de divs e etc...

A solução para meu caso foi posicionar as divs com position: absolute;
cada div ficou em uma posição especifica e realizei loops de uma pagina inteira para gerar o PDF d todas as folhas.
Mais um detalhe que pode ser útil: Para criar bordas no css 2.1 o elemento border: 2px solid#000; não funciona, e necessário utilizar  border: thin solid #000;

Mais um detalhe que se mostrou útil, programar o css com o pdf já renderizado, uma vez que a formatação do css é exibida de maneira diferente no hmtl por conta do css2.1.
Espero ter contribuído.